# Terminal not working

Tags: gnome-terminal

I can't type anything into the terminal. Just nothing shows up in the terminal window no matter what I do. Most web searching on the problem starts with, "type  --- into terminal" which of course isn't helping.

Anyone else have this problem? What do I do?

Comment: Is this any help? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1022945  --Read the whole article

Comment: did you by any chance changed the color of the terminal and the color of the text you're typing. for eg white back ground of terminal with text would cause the problem.?

Comment: install different terminals and try them in Alt-F2: gnome-terminal, xfce4-terminal, lxterm, xterm

Comment: Have a look [http://askubuntu.com/questions/171449/shell-does-not-show-typed-in-commands-reset-works-but-what-happened](http://askubuntu.com/questions/171449/shell-does-not-show-typed-in-commands-reset-works-but-what-happened)

Answer (score 8):

I had my theme in terminal to match my theme in Ubuntu which was Black on Black, so I was typing, but couldn't see anything. Very easy to fix by:

Terminal > Edit > Profile Prefrences > Colors

Then deselect "use colours from system Theme."