# Bash - Put process in the background

Tags: bash, process

How can I put a process into the background in a script? I tried this but it does not work:

```
!#/bin/bash
vi &
```

Comment: Btw, your shebang line should be `#!/bin/bash`, not `!#/bin/bash`. When you use `vi &`, it does start `vi` in the background, but you just can't interact with it because it's in the background. To call it to the foreground after running `vi &`, use `fg`. This probably doesn't solve your problem, so it would be better to tell use what your script needs to do (ex. The user edits in vi while the script does something)

Comment: My script have to run vi in background and after 10 minutes shut this program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vi has to be called to the foreground to interact with it:

```
#!/bin/bash
vi &
pid=$!
fg
for times in {1..600}
do
        kill -0 "$pid" || break
        sleep 1
done
kill "$pid"
reset
```

Also, in this case, we have a loop 600 times to wait 1 second so that we can check if `vi` is still running. If not, then we can stop waiting and continue with the script.

In addition, [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/172747/372607) explains why `reset` is used at the end.